# Matplotlib gives This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code gives error:
Matplotlib gives This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Create the vectors X and Y
x = np.array(range(100))
y = x ** 2

# Create the plot
plt.plot(x,y)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are likely missing some kind of shared library. How did you install matplotlib? Is QT installed?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to install PyQt5 `/EnvironmentDirectoryPath/pip3 install PyQt5` .

Found details at https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#understanding-the-correct-version-to-install

I also installed it system wide with `sudo apt-get install python-qt4` with no ill effects.